# Taglib read ID3v2 tags from arbitrary file c++

Tags: c++, audio, metadata, taglib, id3v2

I'm trying to use the TagLib C++ API to read ID3v2 metadata from an arbitrary audio file. This file is not necessarily an `.mp3` file, and may be of the other common audio formats. I have the following:

```cpp
std::string readId3v2Tag(std::string filePath, std::string tagName) {
    // read from file
    TagLib::FileRef f(filePath.c_str());
    if (!f.isNull() && f.file()) {
        // get tags from property map
        TagLib::PropertyMap tags = f.file()->properties();
        if (tags.find(tag) != tags.end()) {
            return std::string(tags[tag][0].toCString());
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I input an ID3v2 frame name, it doesn't return anything. I believe this is because the `f.file()->properties()` map contains TagLib's tag format. I must be able to access ID3v2 frames by name.

I have been told to use the `ID3v2` class, however I don't see how to access this from a file, and am having trouble reading the API docs. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always read the manual: [it tells you](https://taglib.org/api/classTagLib_1_1FileRef.html#a671babf554c896db7d6f6a79c4461dcf) to not use the `file()` approach. Also `properties()` won't give you ID3v2 tag **frames** - you should iterate all of them to see their keys and values.

Instead

- use `MPEG::File` (see [manual](https://taglib.org/api/classTagLib_1_1MPEG_1_1File.html)) and from there go/read on
- over `ID3v2Tag()` (see [manual](https://taglib.org/api/classTagLib_1_1MPEG_1_1File.html#aebe5029bca925e9ed7002b00244c1240))
- to `frameList()` (see [manual](https://taglib.org/api/classTagLib_1_1ID3v2_1_1Tag.html#a5094b04654b0912db9dca61de11f4663)).

It's pretty straightforward once the terms are clear: a file can have zero to multiple **tags**, where a ID3v2 tag can have one to multiple **frames**. The file alone however can also have multiple **properties** that are unbound to tags (i.e. audio duration, bit depth...) - no wonder that none of your **frame** names you search for won't show up in the file's **properties**.